# RESTful API Doc using SLIM and SWAGGER?

Tags: php, slim, swagger-php

I am new to this stuff but I love it. I made a little REST Api using the Slim Framework. Now I would like to have an ongoing documentation about it. I think swagger is the right choice but I have not found out yet how to integrate it ?

Cheers & thanks for your patience :)

Comment: I've heard good thing about Swagger - are there any docs on the associated website? However, my guess is this topic is too broad here - bear in mind that Stack Overflow is for programming problems involving code. If you can give it a go and edit this question about _what_ you are stuck on, that would be great.

Comment: I dont know how to integrate swagger in my PHP project. They offer a php client on Github and a Server integration tutorial for Java but this didnt take me further. At the moment I have no idea which steps I have to take. I dont want to put comments in my source and then run a tool which create s a documentation.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I think you are looking for this project: [zircote/swagger-php](https://github.com/zircote/swagger-php)

[Here](https://zircote.github.io/swagger-php/) you'll find how to generate the doc on user request to a URL.

Basically you have to annotate your code with the Swagger Annotations, then create another route in Slim with a code similar to this:

```
<?php
use Swagger\Swagger;
$swagger = new Swagger('/project/root/top_level');
header("Content-Type: application/json")
echo $swagger->getResource('/pet', array('output' => 'json'));
```

And it will generate the Swagger API docs on the fly for you.

Comment: thanks! but how do I integrate the swagger-UI with that then?

Comment: got it up and running :)

Comment: @user2942586 Would you be so kind as to explain how you got it up and running?

Comment: @LeonardChallis You need to install swagger-ui: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui and make it point to the swagger route.

Comment: Thanks @adosaiguas

Answer (score 6):

A short update to the answer of adosaiguas:

When using [Slim Framework 4.0](https://www.slimframework.com/) and [zircote/swagger-php](https://github.com/zircote/swagger-php)
one can provide an api endpoint providing the swagger / OpenAPI 3.0 json description using the following code:

```
use function OpenApi\scan;

 /**
 * @OA\Get(
 *     path="/openapi",
 *     tags={"documentation"},
 *     summary="OpenAPI JSON File that describes the API",
 *     @OA\Response(response="200", description="OpenAPI Description File"),
 * )
 */
$app->get('/openapi', function ($request, $response, $args) {
    $swagger = scan('--PATH TO PROJECT ROOT--');
    $response->getBody()->write(json_encode($swagger));
    return $response->withHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
});
```